# The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting

Tags: asp.net, iis, profiler

I made a website using the asp.net 4.0. I have deployed it to my local IIS. Need to do profiler in Visual Studio 2010. When I click the run profiler button I get the error like below.

"The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://xxx/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

What's getting wrong? I to solve this problem.

Comment: Does the site run successfully in IIS when you browse out to it?

Comment: Try turning  off friendly error messages in your browser to see the real error.

Comment: Yes, the site has no problem.

Comment: I was using the profiler in the Vs2010 to run performance. I got this error box.

Comment: Can you check the error reported in the IIS server logs and EventViewer - That will help

Answer (score 6):

This issue can occur if the target site is using an external settings file.

You might review the bugreport on this issue someone filed at connect.microsoft.com

[Possible problem cause w/Profiler, IIS](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587200/performance-profiler-does-not-handle-external-appsettings-file)

Comment: What, if you don't use an external settings file? At least, I think I don't... How do I check, if I use an external settings file?

Comment: See if you have a appSettings element in your web.config that includes a "configSource" attribute.

Comment: And now it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was in the *location* tag:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

The Profiler ignored it during Web.config modifications and added duplicate sections that were already defined within the *location* tag. Therefore resulting Web.config was considered as broken by IIS and 500 error was being returned.

**Common approach** how to determine a root of the issue: when the Profiler modified the config and **before** the exception thrown (about 1 second) you can see modified Web.config in your project folder (next to newly created backup of the original file). At this time you need to "catch" (copy & paste) modified Web.config and then use it as regular configuration file in your project. Now when you open your project in browser, IIS will show what exactly is wrong (details of the "500" exception).

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config changing the attribute of the appSettings from "configSource" to "file" worked for me.

```
<appSettings configsource="..."> to <appSettings file="...">
```

Answer (score -6):

I had the same issue. The problem was in `web.config`. After I fixed it, I did not get this error anymore.

Comment: what exactly did you fix?

Comment: I really do not rememeber what it was, but maybe you can create new web.config without any setting, and copy your old web.config one section after another, then you can recognize which one of them makes the problem.